# How to build keras custom loss function which has additional penalty term to consider previous prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I would like to build regression model using keras custom loss function. My model's specificity is I put additional penalty term in my loss function when my current prediction is bigger than my previous prediction.

I will explain more with toy data.

```
import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

x_train = x_train[:100]
x_test = x_test[:30]

y1 = [*range(30, 0, -1)]
y2 = [*range(40, 0, -1)]
y3 = [*range(10, 0, -1)]
y4 = [*range(20, 0, -1)]

y5 = [*range(13, 0, -1)]
y6 = [*range(17, 0, -1)]


y_train = np.array(y1+y2+y3+y4)
y_test = np.array( y5+y6)
```

Let's use only 130 images from mnist and each image has label. Let assume the labels keep decreasing until it matchs 0 and then the next round starts. Their are 6 scenarios4 scenarios are training dataset, and 2 are test dataset.

training ( 30 ~ 1 40 ~ 1 10~1 20 ~1 )
test ( 13 ~ 1 17 ~1)

Then, build simple regresiion model.

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer =  tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
```

Here's the custom loss function.

```
list_previous_label = [100]
list_true_label = [100]

weight = 1


def model_loss(list_previous_label, list_true_label, weight):

    @tf.function
    def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):

        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float64)
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float64)
        
        previous_prediction = tf.cast(list_previous_label[-1], tf.float64)
        previous_true = tf.cast(list_true_label[-1], tf.float64)
        
        violation_term = tf.cast(tf.math.maximum( (y_pred - previous_prediction) , 0), tf.float64)
          
        list_true_label.append(y_true)
        list_previous_label.append(y_pred)
        
        #print(violation_term)
        if previous_true < y_true:
            return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
        
        else: return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1) + (violation_term ** 2) * weight
    return my_loss
```

And finialize using fit.

```
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = model_loss(list_previous_label, list_true_label, weight) )

# fit 
history  = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose =2)
```

My first question is this loss function code is right for that purpose?

If so, I have two concerns regarding this custom loss function.

The first one is whether list_true_label and list_previous_label are re-make each epoch (list_previous_label = [100]
list_true_label = [100]).

The second is whether my if-condition in loss function works well. I put if condition for the case when the new scenario initiate, such as (30 ~ 1 40 ~ 1 10~1 20 ~1 // 1-> 40 , 1 ->10, 1->20)

Of course the prediction does not works well, I wnat to know my codes are okay or there is better way to express my purpose.

Here's the full toy code:

```
import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

x_train = x_train[:100]
x_test = x_test[:30]

y1 = [*range(30, 0, -1)]
y2 = [*range(40, 0, -1)]
y3 = [*range(10, 0, -1)]
y4 = [*range(20, 0, -1)]

y5 = [*range(13, -1, -1)]
y6 = [*range(17, -1, -1)]


y_train = np.array(y1+y2+y3+y4)
y_test = np.array( y5+y6)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x1 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputs)
x2 = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(x1)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer =  tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

list_previous_label = [100]
list_true_label = [100]

weight = 1


def model_loss(list_previous_label, list_true_label, weight):

    @tf.function
    def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):

        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float64)
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float64)
        
        previous_prediction = tf.cast(list_previous_label[-1], tf.float64)
        previous_true = tf.cast(list_true_label[-1], tf.float64)
        
        violation_term = tf.cast(tf.math.maximum( (y_pred - previous_prediction) , 0), tf.float64)
          
        list_true_label.append(y_true)
        list_previous_label.append(y_pred)
        
        #print(violation_term)
        if previous_true < y_true:
            return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
        
        else: return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1) + (violation_term ** 2) * weight
    return my_loss

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = model_loss(list_previous_label, list_true_label, weight) )

# fit 
history  = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=10, verbose =2)
```

I searched how to build custom loss function in keras, and build it using them. But I am not sure it is the right way.